# How to filter record based on criteria in duplicate row

Tags: sql-server

I have this data

```
ID Name Address BankAc TranType

1  Raj  Indore   22     check

1  Raj  Mumbai   22     check

2  Ram  Indore   21     online

2  Ram  Indore   21     check

2  Ram  Indore   21     check

3  Moh  Mumbai   22     online
3  Moh  Delhi    22     online
```

I want output

```
ID Name Address BankAc TranType  MigFlag
1  Raj  Indore   22     check     Y
1  Raj  Mumbai   22     check     Y
2  Ram  Indore   21     check     N
2  Ram  Indore   21     online    Y
2  Ram  Indore   21     check     N
3  Moh  Mumbai   22     online    Y
3  Moh  Delhi    22     online    Y
```

TranType is Online (FirstPriority) and all record having the same value then its flgg set to 'Y' and remainging will be 'N'
If Address is different and TranType is check then with flag should be 'Y'
If address is same but TranType is diffrent , so make Y which has tranType is online other wise 'N'

Comment: your explanation for MigFlag is confusing. Can you reword what you actually mean. ?

Comment: if address is different and trantype is same then both Flag True,,,,                                                  if address is same and trantype is same then any one can be True......            if address is same and trantype is diffrent and online is priority